# Most efficient sorting algorithm for sorted sub-sequences

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I have several sorted sequences of numbers of type long (ascending order) and want to generate one master sequence that contains all elements in the same order. I look for the most efficient sorting algorithm to solve this problem. I target C#, .Net 4.0 and thus also welcome ideas targeting parallelism.

Here is an example:
s1 = 1,2,3,5,7,13
s2 = 2,3,6
s3 = 4,5,6,7,8
resulting Sequence = 1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,13

Edit: When there are two (or more) identical values then the order of those two (or more) does not matter.

Comment: Time efficient? Space efficient? Some other efficiency parameter?

Comment: Time efficient or space efficient?

Comment: You can do each two sub's merge in O(n) complexity using a simple for loop.

Comment: Lol, seems to be much less a trivial question as was hinted by early commenters, given there are 4 completely opposing answers popping up <10 minutes after I posted. Just wanted to point to my original question asking for ideas for the most efficient algorithm for my specific problem, which means I definitely do not look for a C# built-in function because non that I am aware of optimize on the fact that the sub-sequences are already sorted.

Comment: @Freddy Just thought it's worth mentioning, there are general purpose sorting algorithms that do take that into account, the Java and Python default sorting algorithms for example (but not .Nets).  You could lookup TimSort on wikipedia if you're interested, but it would likely be overkill for you, since you've already identified the sorted subsets.

Comment: @Servy, fair point, I was referring to .Net without explicitly mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Turns out that with all the algorithms... It's still faster the simple way:

```
private static List<T> MergeSorted<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sortedBunches)
{
    var list = sortedBunches.SelectMany(bunch => bunch).ToList();

    list.Sort();

    return list;
}
```

And for legacy purposes...

Here is the final version by prioritizing:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> MergeSorted<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sortedInts) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<T>>(sortedInts.Select(ints => ints.GetEnumerator()).Where(e => e.MoveNext()));

        enumerators.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.Current.CompareTo(e2.Current));

        while (enumerators.Count > 1)
        {
            yield return enumerators[0].Current;

            if (enumerators[0].MoveNext())
            {
                if (enumerators[0].Current.CompareTo(enumerators[1].Current) == 1)
                {
                    var tmp = enumerators[0];
                    enumerators[0] = enumerators[1];
                    enumerators[1] = tmp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                enumerators.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        do
        {
            yield return enumerators[0].Current;
        } while (enumerators[0].MoveNext());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried it out but it does not work as expected. I tested it with an array of two arrays of type long each containing hundred thousands of values. It seems to be trapped in an infinite loop or is incredibly inefficient for small number of sequences but many elements per sequence...or...possible bug?

Comment: Could you please pastebin the arrays you've used?

Comment: hardly possible (with hundreds of thousands of elements) but here is a small subset: 634398912001390000
634398912001540000
634398912002130000
634398912003100000
634398912003120000
634398912003120000
634398912003130000

Comment: And how exactly do you expect them to be merged? It's a simple sorted array of longs. You want to merge the digits? What?

Comment: I want the values of type long to be sorted in ascending order. Each sequence contains similar values of type long. As you can see the sample I pasted are values of type long in strictly ascending order.Not sure what you are asking cause I thought it was clear. Can you explain what is unclear please?

Comment: Well, there is nothing to merge-sort here. I made a list of size 100, which element being an array of 1000 random long numbers an ascending order. The method took about 5 seconds to end and the results were perfect. If you could give me an example of arrays for which this doesn't work, this would be good. By example I mean give me all of the arrays, separated from one another. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) is a simple way to give me a giant code.

Comment: first sequence: 634398912001390000,634398912001540000,634398912002130000,634398912003100000,634398912003120000,634398912003120000,634398912003130000,634398912003190000,634398912003770000,634398912003860000,634398912004110000 , second sequence: 634398912000310000,634398912000320000,634398912001160000,634398912001410000,634398912003190000,634398912003460000,634398912010570000,634398912011160000,634398912011170000,634398912011190000,634398912011210000

Comment: it takes my current algorithm about 4.4 seconds to merge 1.4 million long values that are contained in each sequence simply by comparing the first item of each sequence, taking away the lower one and adding it to the resulting sequence.

Comment: @Freddy What's your current algorithm? It doesn't sound like everything will be really sorted eventually, IMO

Comment: And it merges the arrays you gave me perfectly (in less than 4ms): 634398912000310000, 634398912000320000, 634398912001160000, 634398912001390000, 634398912001410000, 634398912001540000, 634398912002130000, 634398912003100000, 634398912003120000, 634398912003120000, 634398912003130000, 634398912003190000, 634398912003190000, 634398912003460000, 634398912003770000, 634398912003860000, 634398912004110000, 634398912010570000, 634398912011160000, 634398912011170000, 634398912011190000, 634398912011210000

Comment: I misunderstood what you said about your algorithm. Mine is very similar, except it adds K-Way logic when you want to merge many arrays (it couples them, and merges them. Then it couples the results and merges, again and again, until only one result is left).

Comment: Sorry, I am by now completely lost what you are trying to say here. I thought my explanation in my question made a lot of sense. Can you still point out which part is unclear, I am more than happy to change the wording if it helps. I appreciate your help and code samples but fact is your code as it current stands does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Freddy In your question you provided several arrays, each containing several numbers. Each array was pre-sorted and you wanted an array containing all numbers from all arrays, sorted. My answer provides as solution to that issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: It is highly inefficient either because it contains a bug or because the algorithm is not suitable for large sequences. I pointed out to you that it takes eternities to merge two lists containing a million elements each. A simple loop over the smallest elements in each sequence merges in about 5 seconds. Yours does not even finish minutes later. I think the reason is you use inserts and remove of lists, which are very expensive operations.

Comment: You're right, you should use the prioritize implementation. I'll edit so the answer will only contain what you need.

Comment: It works pretty much like Thomash's answer, except it also works for more than two arrays. This works for any number of arrays, with any number of elements in each (And it does not waste memory on it!)

Comment: Yorye, your solution with priority works works very efficiently. My apologies that I did not make it clearer that I was the whole time referring to your K-Way without priority queue implementation which is either buggy or highly inefficient for this type of task. I mark your solution as answer, the algorithm with priority queue merges 1.4 million items in each sequence in about 250 milliseconds and that without any parallelization going on. Thanks.

Comment: @Freddy My K-Way solution was indeed slow, and memory-consuming. I think that priority is pretty great for this task, and glad I helped! (1.4mil in 250ms sounds great!)

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, it definitely is fast enough for my purposes. I could push faster if I wanted by parallelizing the task by breaking down each sequence into pre-defined buckets and merge each sub-sequence and later add the resulting sequences together, knowing that there is no overlap between one subsequence to the next. Example. S1, and S2 -> goal: merge into MasterSequence. I can break down S1 and S2 into 2 sub-sequences each (for example if total values run from 1..1000, break down into subsequences of S11 1..500,  S12 501..1000), merge, then add each sub-master to the total master

Comment: You know, the thing that amazes me, is that I've done `list.SelectMany(longs => longs).ToList();` and then called `.Sort()` on it. It turns out to be a bit faster for small amount of arrays with any amount of elements, and many time faster for big amount of arrays with any amount of elements.

Comment: I have not tried to optimize the routine yet, but I will look at it later, so far it performs well enough as is, I am not experienced enough in knowing which methods on enumerations and other collections perform better or worse, thus I need to actually run performance tests on each. Anyway, thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: I've performed tests on both, and the simple solution proved to be much better. It also uses less memory. For the case of 2 arrays, each 1.4mil elements on my lazy computer: Priority-1135ms vs Simple-828ms. As you increase the number of arrays, the difference increases. For 100,000 arrays, each with 2 elements, you can see a significant difference: Priority-10.5sec vs Simple-101ms (!!!)

Comment: do you mind posting your simple K-way algo again? I will then trouble shoot what is wrong on my end.

Comment: When I say "Simple" - I was referring to the the currently first solution in my answer - the short method. Not the K-Way algo, just to clarify. The short method solution in the beginning of my answer is the fastest without a doubt.

Comment: Only limitations with this whole approach is that the assumption is that the sequences to be merged are "completed". When working with BlockingCollections where more items may be added into a nonBlocking Queue then one would need to be a bit careful to correctly fence a certain subset of data otherwise the result may not be correct. In that just comparing the lowest values in each sequence with each other and removing the global min would prevent errors but its orders of magnitudes slower. But that was not part of the question so I take care of that myself.

Comment: @Freddy I agree, though that wasn't your question. BlockingCollections should be handled differently in this case.

Comment: Any ideas how to operate on blocking collections? I ultimately operate on blocking collections that contain wrapping objects which themselves contain the long value by which the objects are sorted in each blocking collection.

Comment: It is a completely different question, then, which requires a different approach. I suggest opening a question for that.

Comment: fair enough, was just wondering, it should not be hard to get started using Linq I guess, but whether its the optimal solution is a different question. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: It depends on how the BlockingCollections are interacted with, as well. Depends on the general flow of motion, in code.

Answer (score 4):

Just merge the sequences. You do not have to sort them again.

Comment: if he merged them as is he would get 1,2,3,5,7,13,2,3,6,4,5,6,7,8 surely? why not instead of sorting the 3 individually then trying to merge them, stick all 3 together in a haphazard order and just sort the final long one once?

Comment: That depends on the merging algorithm.

Comment: @RhysW: An n-way merge is not the same as appending.

Comment: @RhysW The numbers you gave would be the result of "concatting" the sequences, not merging them.

Comment: How so? And what merge/sort algorithm are you talking about in case you look for a C# built-in method?

Comment: @RhysW What you describe is called *appending*. Google **Mergesort** for a definition of *merging*.

Comment: My mistake, i havent had my caffeine today, slipping a little, thanks for the relevant tips though you 3 as opposed to ripping into my mistake, its much appreciated

Comment: @Sven, when you say "merge" which specific algo are you referring to in regards to my problem? I spoke of "merging" more in generalized terms, meaning, combining the sequences while preserving the same order.

Comment: @Sven, is that the fastest way to do it? I wonder because I could split up each sequence and have several divide-and-conquer algorithms work on it in parallel. Would this not beat your suggestion?

Comment: I guess you could also run several simple merge routines in parallel, given one can split the sequences into sub-sequences at "cutoffs" that can be determined for each sequence. Anyone with experience in doing that?

Comment: Sven, your suggestion did not provide the most efficient way to get the task done. I apologize that I was a little thick on the terminology used but essentially my starting point was to do a element by element comparison of the lowest value and then remove it from the given sequence...rinse...and repeat. But it was not fast enough. Thanks though for all the input and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

There is no .NET Framework method that I know of to do a K-way merge. Typically, it's done with a priority queue (often a heap). It's not difficult to do, and it's quite efficient. Given K sorted lists, together holding N items, the complexity is O(N log K).

I show a simple binary heap class in my article [A Generic Binary Heap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789). In [Sorting a Large Text File](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=674), I walk through the creation of multiple sorted sub-files and using the heap to do the K-way merge. Given an hour (perhaps less) of study, and you can probably adapt that to use in your program.

Comment: this sounds very interesting, will definitely take a look, thanks for the hints and links. Will revert after toying with it.

Comment: Jim, thank you for your valuable input, I implemented a k-way merge with priority queue, it performs very well. I had to mark another proposed solution as answer because it provided the code to go along with. But I keep on reading your articles and derive much value from it, given I am not working in this field, thus my apologizes for incorrect terminology used.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to merge your sequences like in a merge sort.

And this is parallelizable:

1. merge sequences (1 and 2 in 1/2), (3 and 4 in 3/4), …
2. merge sequences (1/2 and 3/4 in 1/2/3/4), (5/6 and 7/8 in 5/6/7/8), …
3. …

Here is the merge function :

```
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size_merged_seq; i++)
{
  if (j < size_seq1 && seq1[j] < seq2[k])
  {
    merged_seq[i] = seq1[j];
    j++;
  }
  else
  {
    merged_seq[i] = seq2[k];
    k++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the leftovers when you hit the end of either input sequence.

Comment: @Thomash, thanks for your input, I implemented something very similar albeit more generalized to handle n-sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is to merge them with each other one by one. However, this will require `O(n*k^2)` time, where `k` is number of sequences and `n` is the average number of items in sequences. However, using divide and conquer approach you can lower this time to O(n*k*log k). The algorithm is as follows:

1. Divide k sequences to k/2 groups, each of 2 elements (and 1 groups of 1 element if k is odd).
2. Merge sequences in each group. Thus you will get k/2 new groups.
3. Repeat until you get single sequence.

Comment: And if you use a priority queue and a K-way merge algorithm, it becomes O(n log k).

Comment: @JimMischel: yes! I just noticed you answer, upvoting for it!