# What is the fastest sorting alogrithm for combining pre-sorted sets

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dataset, complexity-theory

Lets say that I have sets that I know are already sorted such as {0,2,10,23,65} and {3,5,8..}. What would be the best sorting algorithm that could combine any number of pre-sorted sets into one sorted set? For how effecient would this type of sorting be?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450138/most-efficient-sorting-algorithm-for-sorted-sub-sequences/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to *sort* them, you need to *merge*. This is done in `O(M+N)` using a simple loop that keeps two indexes looking at the current element of the two parts, adding the smaller of the two to the final sequence, and advancing the index by one.

Here is pseudocode:

```
int[] parts1, parts2 // Sorted parts
int i = 0, j = 0;
while i != parts1.Length || j != parts2.Length
    if i != parts1.Length || j != parts2.Length
        if parts1[i] < parts2[j]
            res.Add(parts1[i++])
        else
            res.Add(parts2[j++])
    else if i != parts1.Length
        res.Add(parts1[i++])
    else
        res.Add(parts2[j++])
```

At each step the loop advances either `i` or `j`, executing `parts1.Lenght + part2.Length` times.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to compare the head of lists you have, take the smallest one, and add it to a sorted set.  Repeat until all lists are empty.

Efficiency-wise, it's always linear in time.  It will take as long as the number of items you have to merge in total.

This is actually the second stage of [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are `O(n)` elements in `O(k)` sets.  A standard merge is going to be `O(n * k)`.

If you only have 2 sets, this is not a big deal.  If you have 1000 it might be.  In that case you can keep a priority queue of sets organized by their next smallest element.  This variant is `O(n log(k))`.